# transport.send(msg) not executed

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, transport

i have an activity where i call the send method in below class..in my code it hangs at transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getallreceipents())..i have tried try cath but it dint cath any exception there.
and one thing is when i use gmail host smtp.gmail.com and username and password of gmail account it works.

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;

public Mail() {
    _host = "mail.namknights.org"; // default smtp server
    _port = "587"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "587"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
            .getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
        session.setDebug(true);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                _body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));
        msg.setDataHandler(handler);
        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);
        Log.v("mas", "Email is about to send");
        // send email
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(_host, 587, _user, _pass);
        Transport.send(msg);
        Log.v("mas", "Email was  send");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v("mas", "Email was  not send");
        return false;

    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", false);

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._to = toArr;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._from = string;
}

public void setSubject(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._subject = string;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If it works with Gmail, your code is essentially correct.  If it's failing with some other mail server, it's likely a configuration problem.  Use session.setDebug(true) to get the debugging output from JavaMail, which might provide clues as to what's going wrong.

Note that you might need to set some timeout properties if you're stuck waiting for a server that's never going to respond.  See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).

Finally, [you shouldn't need all that socket factory stuff in your code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: even i am using port 465 in exception it is showing like `03-05 10:55:07.118: D/e mail(1181): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.namknights.org, port: 25;
03-05 10:55:07.118: D/e mail(1181):   nested exception is:
03-05 10:55:07.118: D/e mail(1181):  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x256a80: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
03-05 10:55:07.118: D/e mail(1181): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/
`

Comment: Please edit your original question to show how you updated your code based on my previous suggestion, so I can see what you're doing wrong.  You're definitely doing something wrong with the property configuration, but I can't tell you what without seeing the details.

Comment: i updated...i have set timeout property for 50000 and also i have changed transport arguments...now i am geting `03-05 14:23:06.498: I/System.out(2130): DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
03-05 14:23:06.519: I/System.out(2130): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
03-05 14:23:06.519: I/System.out(2130): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.namknights.org", port 465, isSSL true
`

Comment: Your code is all messed up.  You're setting a bunch of socket factory properties that you don't need.  You're setting other properties of the form "mail.smtp.*", as if you were using the "smtp" protocol, but then you're calling getTransport with "smtps".  The property names have to match the value you use with getTransport, so they should be changed to "mail.smtps.*".  that should make the connection timeout work.  **Why** you're unable to connect is a different issue; see the [JavaMail FAQ for debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug)